# Promoting website

Tags: seo, dns, search-engine

I am creating a new website and hope will be lanched in 2/3 months.
basically I am a programmer and have no idea how to promote my site against my competitors.

What I want to lanch is only for Germany and the competitors are doing this business from last 15 years and are very well known here in Germany.

Is there any book recomendation or any other source that can help me in promoting my site and attracting the User to use my site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good source of knowledge is Googles SEO  Starter Guide located here http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/11/googles-seo-starter-guide.html

The other is SEOchat website.

Comment: also you can try [SEOgenie Automated SEO Solutions](http://www.seo-genie.com)